# Constructor with two arguments Java

Tags: java

I have some trouble when I want to use a method from another class.

So I have to print to the console the interestRate and the account type from my class AccountType,
and in to my class Customer and I have already done it fine with the balance where I call the class BankAccount.

```
BankAccount balance = new BankAccount();
```

and that is called from a constructor with only one argument , but now that I want to call a constructor with two arguments I get an error.

```
       public void printAccountInformation()
       {
          BankAccount balance = new BankAccount(); // This work fine
          AccountType rate = new AccountType();   // but here i get error because the constructor in the account type takes two arguments
          AccountType type = new AccountType();   // but here i get error because the constructor in the account type takes two arguments

          System.out.println("Greetings dear: " + name); 
            System.out.println("Your street: " + street); 
             System.out.println("Your town " + town);
              System.out.println("Your postalCode " + postalCode);
               System.out.println("Your PhoneNumber " + telephoneNumber);
                System.out.println("User balance: " + balance.getBalance());
                System.out.println("User Account type: " + type.getAccountType());
                System.out.println("Your InterestRate Is: " + rate.getInterestRate());

   }
```

And here is my AccountType class

```
public class AccountType
{
  // Attributes

  private String accountNameType;
  private float interestRate = 0.0f;



  // Constructor 
  public AccountType(String types, float rate)
  {
      accountNameType = types;
      interestRate = rate;

  }
  // accessor 
  public String getAccountType()
    {
        return accountNameType;
    }

public float getInterestRate()
    {
        return interestRate;
    }

}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You've noted yourself that the constructor takes two arguments, yet you've passed 0.

Comment: Have you tried defining a no argument constructor in the class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to initialize an empty AccountType object, then you need to add a no argument default constructor.

```
public AccountType() { }
```

If you need to set class variables after the object is initialized then you will need to add the appropriate setter methods.

```
public void setAccountType(String accountNameType){
    this.accountNameType = accountNameType;
}

public void setInterestRate(float interestRate){
    this.interestRate = interestRate;
}
```

So in your main class.

```
AccountType accountType = new AccountType();
accountType.setAccountType("savings");
accountType.setInterestRate(10.0);
```

Comment: This is my assignment : The banking system is now to be prepared for handling different types of accounts
such as saving accounts, credit accounts, wage accounts etc. To handle information
about different types of accounts a new class AccountType is to be added to the
project. This class should have two attributes: a string to hold the name of the
account type and an interest rate (all accounts of given type have the same interest
rate). Write this class including a constructor that takes type and interest rate as
arguments and accessor methods for the attributes.

Comment: @user2984388 then I bet you do want the two arguments constructor, not an empty one, and that the type and rate should be provided externally.

Answer (score 2):

Just pass a "typeName" and "interestRate" by parameter to your constructor

```
AccountType type = new AccountType("savings", 0.012f);
```

Comment: But what if i want the interestRate to be set in the AccountType class and not again here ?

Comment: I mean lets say in  accountType the InterestRate is 2.0 and will always be this .. and i dont want to type 2.0 again and again ?

Comment: @user2984388 Then don't provide a two arguments constructor where is up to the client to configure the interest rate but constant into the AccountType.

Comment: Maybe the real question is why you are instantiating AccountType with the same parameters over and over again and not reusing the same instance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the arguments when you call the constructor:

```
AccountType acct = new AccountType("Type R", 1.0f);
```

Answer (score 0):

add this one to your AccountType class

```
public AccountType(){
}
```

Comment: And then i will be able to show , predefined attributes instead of haveing to set them again and again ?